# Spring data jpa sum with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, spring-data

I am trying to run this simple query but without success.
Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select kategorie, sum(amount) amount from Transaction where date between ?1 and ?2 group by kategorie")
List<Transaction> countCashPaymentInMonth(Date from, Date to);
```

In mysql is query working fine.

I am receiving

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column "id" was not find
```

I am using

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
1.3.3.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
List<Object[]> countCashPaymentInMonth(Date from, Date to);
```